# Custom Three20 TTThumbsViewController or not?

Tags: xcode, three20

I need to create something like the Three20 TTThumbsViewController, but each cell needs a caption of the image and I need to specify the number and size of cells in the grid.
It also needs to send the user to another view by tapping the Captioned image in the grid.

Hope it doesn't sound too complicated, 
My question is:

I am using three20, should or can I customize the TTThumbsViewController or must I try create a Three20 table with custom cells in a grid format like TTThumbsViewController ?

Is three20 a good option in this scenario?

any guidance will be appreciated

Thanks
Brett

Comment: Hey Brett, facing the same scenario right now. How did you go about?